# Unexpected token var when creating variable in if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am creating variable and using it in for statement

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   console.log(i)
}
```

It is working properly and resulting from 1-10;

When I write same in the `if` condition

```
if(var value = 10) {
   console.log("Evaluate");
}
```

It is resulting `Unexpected token var`.
When I declare a variable (var a = 10), resulting the same error. Is there any issue.

Answer (score 2):

An `if` statement only accepts an *expression* inside (something that evaluates to a value). Something like `var value = ...` is a *statement* - rather than evaluating to a value, it *does* something (namely, creates a local variable bound to the name `value`). So, since `var value = ...` cannot be evaluated as an expression, an error is thrown.

Some things can be evaluated both as statements and expressions (such as functions), but variable *creation* is not one of them.

Note that variable *assignment* is possible inside an `if`, because assignment *does* evaluate to the value assigned:

```js
var value;
if(value = 10) {
  console.log('value now has the value 10');
}
```

But that's *really* confusing to read - a reader of the code will likely immediately worry whether that's a typo or not. Better to assign variables outside of an `if` condition, whenever possible.

Only use `var` when you want to create a new variable. If you simply want to *check* a variable (for example, check whether the variable named `value` is `10`), then just print that variable name, and use a comparison operator (`===`, not `=`):

```
if (value === 10) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I declaring variable inside `(var a = 10)` brakets, same error is showing

Comment: As expected - like I said, you can't create a variable inside an `if` condition (or inside anywhere that an expression is expected), because that's a statement which cannot be parsed as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
var value = 10
```

actually evaluated as the following statements:

```
var value;
value = 10
```

You can not write statement in `if` as *condition*, as the *condition* must be only *expression*:

> An [*expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) that is considered to be either truthy or falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize the variable outside. Use proper operators.

```
var value = 10;
if(value == 10) {
   console.log("Evaluate");
}
else {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable like this:

```js
    var value = 10;
    if(value == 10) {
       console.log("Evaluate");
    }
```